# Download MP3 file from server in sd card in Android

Tags: android

I want to download all mp3 files from server one by one and save into sd card folder. I have no any errors or exception but mp3 does not downloaded and does not show in SD card. Can someone help how to solve this issue.Here is my code.

```
if (imageName.endsWith(mp3_Pattern))
                    {
                        str_DownLoadUrl = namespace + "/DownloadFile/FileName/" + imageName;

                        Log.e("#########  ", "str_DownLoadUrl  = " + str_DownLoadUrl);
                        download_Mp3File(str_DownLoadUrl);

                        strDownLoadStatus = "1";
                        dbhelper.update_DownLoadStatus(imageName, strDownLoadStatus);
                    }

 void download_Mp3File(final String fileUrl) {

        new AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>()
        {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... arg0)
            {
                int count;
                File file = new File(newFolder, System.currentTimeMillis() + imageName);
                try
                {
                    URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
                    URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
                    conexion.connect();
                    // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
                    int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();

                    // downlod the file
                    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

                    byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                    long total = 0;

                    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                        total += count;
                        // publishing the progress....
                        publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / lenghtOfFile));
                        output.write(data, 0, count);
                    }

                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                    input.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                return  null;
            }
        }.execute();

    }
```

Comment: You did not show type and value of 'newFolder'. Please do. You have no logs in your catch block. Please add them so you know what's happenig. Any errors/exceptions in the LogCat?

Comment: Let doInBackground return a string with usefull info. Implement onPostExecute where you can log and Toast the content that string.

Answer (score 0):

place a breakpoint in inputstream object to see is there any stream. then debug output stream to see the results.

Comment: That is not an answer. Such remarks you should post as comment.

Comment: @greenapps: ok i will do that next time.